# Is the Lamprey Vivant dish in Disenchantment related to the creature in the Futurama movies?

Tags: futurama, disenchantment

Is the *Lamprey Vivant* dish in Disenchantment in any way related to the creature in the Futurama movies?

[image: Still from the show, showing the Lamprey Vivant being served]

<sup>Disenchantment: Season 1 Episode 6 - 14:30</sup>

Comment: Probably not, lamprey are a real creature so they’re just directly lifted from our world.

Comment: Yup. Possibly also a reference to the cause of death of Henry I ("a surfeit of lampreys")?

Comment: (You can't stop at just one, trust me...)